# How to find the number of items with more than one occurrence?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The task is to write a function that finds a number of items appearing more than once in an array.

For example:

> countIdentic([3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8]) returns 4

> countIdentic([15,14,13,19,13,14,14,14,7,9,9]) returns 3

I already have a solution but I find it complicated. So maybe there is a more elegant solution to that task?

```js
function countIdentic(arr) {
  var clone = arr.slice(0),  
      test = [],             
      cur,                   
      count = 0;             
  while (clone.length) {
    cur = clone.shift();
    if (test.indexOf(cur) === -1) {
      test.push(cur);
      if (clone.indexOf(cur) >= 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log( countIdentic([3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8]) );

console.log( countIdentic([15,14,13,19,13,14,14,14,7,9,9]) );
```

Comment: I think you should re-word your question.  It seems what you mean to ask is "how many entries are _duplicated_ not how many _duplicates_ are there.  I agree this belongs on codereview, not SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better fitted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set`, so you don't iterate many times over the original array. But that will take some more space complexity :)

*Space complexity:* `O(n)`, where `n` is `arr.length`. Since `seenOnce` and `duplicates` can grow up to `arr.length` size.

*Time complexity:* `O(n)`, where `n` is `arr.length`. Since we iterate over the `arr` only once.

```js
function countIdentic(arr) {
  const seenOnce = new Set();
  const duplicates = new Set();

  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (duplicates.has(item)) {
      return;
    }
    if (seenOnce.has(item)) {
      duplicates.add(item);
      seenOnce.delete(item);
      return;
    }
    seenOnce.add(item);
  });
  return duplicates.size;
}

console.log(countIdentic([3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8]));
console.log(countIdentic([15, 14, 13, 19, 13, 14, 14, 14, 7, 9, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countIdentic(arr) {
   return [... // get number of occurences for every item
     arr.reduce((map, num) => map.set(num, (map.get(num) ?? 0) + 1), new Map)
     .entries()
   ]
   // filter pairs with more than one occurence
   .filter(([num, count]) => count > 1)
   // get the count
   .length;
}

console.log( countIdentic([3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8]) ); 
console.log( countIdentic([15,14,13,19,13,14,14,14,7,9,9]) );
```